# How to fix moving from settingactivity to mainactivity?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have settingactivity and i want the user to move it from settingactivity to mainactivity when the user presses update profile button i tried removing @NonNull but it didn't affect anything i tried to change even Intent also but no effect here is the code

```
package com.example.chat;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button UpdateAccountSettings;
    private EditText userName, userStatus;
    private CircleImageView userProfileImage;
    private String currentUserID;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference RootRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        InitializeFields();
        UpdateAccountSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull View view) {
                UpdateSettings();
            }
        });
    }

    private void InitializeFields() {
        UpdateAccountSettings = findViewById(R.id.update_setting_button);
        userName = findViewById(R.id.set_user_name);
        userStatus = findViewById(R.id.set_profile_status);
        userProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    }

    private void UpdateSettings() {
        String setUserName = userName.getText().toString();
        String setStatus = userStatus.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserName)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Username Is Empty!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setStatus)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Status Is Empty!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            HashMap<String, Object> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
            profileMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
            profileMap.put("name", setUserName);
            profileMap.put("status", setStatus);
            RootRef.child("User").child(currentUserID).setValue(profileMap)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                SendUserToMainActivity();
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile Updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

when i press update profile button it says profile is updated but it doesn't go to main activity
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh `SendUserToMainActivity()` is a function which holds intent.

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh what should i do then

Comment: Data storing in your database properly ? @SiddhMistry

Comment: it should work, your code is right, show me your `MainActivity`

Comment: @Ashish yes it is storing propely

Comment: its too long to show here

Comment: try removing line of  ->mainIntent.addFlags

Comment: @VirRajpurohit no effect

Comment: check my answer, if still confusing let me know in the comments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this in your main activity

```
 private void SendUserToSettingsActivity() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent)
        }
```

and from settings Activity

```
 private void SendUserToMainActivity() {

            finish();
        }
```

I debug your code, the code above is working fine, you added a data change listener in this main activity

```
    private void VerifyUserExistance() {
            String currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("name").exists()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CALLED AGAIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        SendUserToSettingActivity();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

When you update a child from settings activity, the `onDataChange` listener is called, and the new user name which your are setting, is not existing and your else case is calling the settings activity again

MainActivity>SettingsActivity> when an update is called then the settings activity get destroyed but called again from the section above. try the above method, you 'll see the toast 'CALLED AGAIN'

Comment: well is working fine now i just re write the whole code again

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you do not absolutely require the flags with the intent, I would suggest that you remove them for now.

Also, in the code you have shared from Github (https://github.com/sadsouler/MyApplication/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tk/hackeridiot/chat/SettingsActivity.java), the code for the `SendUserToMainActivity()` function is:

```
private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mainIntent);
    finish();
}
```

In this code, you are creating the intent but never using it. Although the code you have shared on StackOverflow does have this part, the code on Github does not. Replace the code on Github to this:

```
private void SendUserToMainActivity()
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
}
```

Also, you should use a debugger or debug messages to know if the program actually reaches this function or not. Although it probably should since you are calling the function, but, it never hurts to check. So, use this code to know if the function is executed using a debug message (or directly use the debugger):

```
private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
    Log.d("debugTag", "Creating an intent to MainActivity...");
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
}
```

Apart from this, I cannot any other error in your code.